# If I need to query (WHERE) any combination of the columns, should I index them all?

Tags: postgresql

If I have 6 columns (includes primary key `id`) and I need to query (where =) any combination of the columns, should I index them all individually? I think I should.

I index them individually instead of multicolumn indexes, because I will query one column at a time too. (any combination of columns including one at a time, and all columns at a time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is an EXPLAIN statement that should answer your question.

```
janbet=> create table aa (n1 integer, n2 integer);
CREATE TABLE
janbet=> create index on aa (n1);
CREATE INDEX
janbet=> create index on aa (n2);
CREATE INDEX
janbet=> insert into aa select (random() * 10^5)::integer, (random() * 10^4)::integer from generate_series(1, (10^4)::integer, 1);
INSERT 0 10000
janbet=> explain select from aa where n1 = 7;
                                QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using aa_n1_idx on aa  (cost=0.40..32.41 rows=1 width=0)
   Index Cond: (n1 = 7)
(2 rows)

janbet=> explain select from aa where n2 = 8;
                                QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using aa_n2_idx on aa  (cost=0.40..32.41 rows=1 width=0)
   Index Cond: (n2 = 8)
(2 rows)

janbet=> explain select from aa where n1 = 7 and n2 = 8;
                             QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using aa_n2_idx on aa  (cost=0.40..32.42 rows=1 width=0)
   Index Cond: (n2 = 8)
   Filter: (n1 = 7)
(3 rows)
```

As you can see in last query above, one index is used and other column value is filtered.

And the same will be in your case - PostgreSQL uses always **at most one index**. This is just how the indexes work - when you use the information from one index, there is no way of applying information from the other.

On the other hand, PostgreSQL works well with multicolumn indexes when only few **first** columns used. E.g. if you `CREATE INDEX ON some_table (a, b, c)`, then `WHERE a=7`, `WHERE a=7 and b=8` and `WHERE a=7 and b=8 and c=9` will use the index, but e.g. `WHERE b=7` will not.

Long story short: there is no way to ensure that index will be used for every combination of six variables other than creating 720 indexes (one for each order), but this is in no way a recommended solution : )

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details explanation. Just one quick question, since the user may filter each column individually. Does it mean I should at least create 6 indexes, one per each column? For other multicolumn indexes, I may decide to have or not. Btw, I knew if I have index(b, c), then I don't need index(b). I will consider this too. Thanks.

Comment: General solution "one index per column, or multicolumn indexes when reasonable" sounds good, and if you want the **best possible** solution you have to analyze possible values of those columns, e.g. if one column has the same value in 99% of rows it might not be worth indexing, because index will be used only in 1% of cases. 
Note that in some cases there would be more than one usable index (like in my last example) and i would expect Postgres planner to choose the best one.

Comment: `if one column has the same value in 99% of rows it might not be worth indexing` is a very good point. All columns are from an html form. There is one column which only has three possible values (radio button values), I think I can leave that column un-indexed. What about a column with 6 possible values? Should I index it or leave it un-indexed too? Btw, thank you very much for your answer again. I have upvoted and marked it as the final answer.

Comment: Index has two main downsides: it consumes your disc space and slows down a operations that modify the table contents. If this table will be used only for SELECTs and you don't have to worry about storage than i guess you can create as many indexes as you want. If this is not the case, it is impossible to give an answer only based on "how many values are in given column".

Comment: Simple example: if i had a boolean column with 99% TRUE and 1% FALSE, but for some reason i expected users to be more interested in FALSE rows, index would be extremaly useful.

Comment: Got it. The last boolean example and its explanation is pretty important and clear to me. Thank you very much!